# Bootstrap-table : eliminate total rows in pagination

Tags: bootstrap-table

Getting total rowcount from server side is quite expensive, so we want to avoid the totalRows part of pagination.

I know how to modify the "Showing 1 to 10 of 800 rows" in the [pagination example](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/).  How do I modify it to eliminate "page 80", and only have the ellipses "..."?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it simply by adding this CSS snippet,

```
//Hides the total count button
li.page-item.page-last{
    display: none;
}
```